# Android x86 change Keyboard layout

Tags: android, android-x86

How can I change the keyboard layout used by Android from the command line?

I installed the Android-x86 release from https://www.android-x86.org/ in a VirtualBox VM. Unfortunately, the VM only boots to command line and I cannot access the GUI. I want to follow the following solution to directly boot into the GUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61247128/12336925

I cannot type the commands as I want and I cannot use vi appropriately because I have a German keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keymaps of the android x86 terminal are stored in

```
/system/usr/keylayout/
```

See here for more information https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files

So you would need to change the files in there or load a new one to get your layout changed.

To solve your problem however i would recommend to create a menu.lst on an usb device and mount it in your VM. After that you can use the terminal to copy the new file over the existing one.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is: to run all the necessary commands, I also need the other keyboard layout, especially to enter special characters. Therefore I used a mapping picture to follow the earlier mentioned guide to activate my GUI and then I changed the keyboard layout using the GUI.